# How to create a database diagram with Enterprise Architect and an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, enterprise-architect, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-diagramming, database-diagram

I need to create a database diagram in Enterprise Architect.

I understand how I can create each table and add the columns by hand.  But that will take me a really long time.

The database is Oracle 11g and I use Oracle SQL Developer.

Is there any way to export/import the database schema into Enterprise Architect ?  I can't figure out how to create a connection to my database.

Comment: What commands did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an ODBC connection to your database. Then you can select a package in the Project Browser, right-click > Code Engineering > Import DB schema from ODBC...